# Select function at compile time based on C++ version

Tags: c++

is there a way to use like:

```
#if (VERSION_C < 20)  //where version_c is the version of C++ the compiler is using

#use FUNCTION1

#elseif use FUNCTION2
```

I want to use C++20 `fmt()` and I understand that I can just use an older way of doing it, but since I am learning to program, I am curious if this is even possible so that a program's source code could be written once and use the most modern features available to the local compile environment...It will compile on my system but it will not compile on another system unless they use the most current preview version,

Thanks for the help guys! (This is my very first question on here)

Comment: You can test __\_\_cplusplus__ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros

Comment: Even better, use `__cpp_lib_format` which specifically targets the `fmt` feature. [Table of detection macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/feature_test).

Comment: FYI, "cross-compiling" means producing programs for one OS while using a different one. Doesn't seem to be revelant here.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [`__cplusplus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros) macro which expands to the date when the current standard was released.

But it's mostly useless, since compilers don't implement all features from a new standard at the same time.

Because of that we have a bunch of separate [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros). The one you're looking for is `__cpp_lib_format`.

It was added in C++20, then its value was changed in C++23 to indicate new improvements to `std::format`.

---

But if you want my opinion, forget about `std::format` for now.

Use [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), which works on all major compilers, and has more features.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. The requirements for this this project require only standard library stuff <grr>

Comment: @LouisCasinelli GCC still doesn't support it, so a portable solution would be to not use it at all.